# Best solutions for implementing simple reporting that are intensive

Tags: performance, reporting, data-processing

Currently we have data in the transaction database (Oracle) and are fetching data through queries to form reports. e.g. fetch all people under company A along with their details and lookup values from some more tables. It looks something like:

```
Select p.name,
p.address,
(select country_name from country where country_id = p.country_id),
...
...
from 
person p, company c, person_file pf...
where c.company_id = p.company_id and c.company_id = 1
.. <all joins and conditions for tables>
```

The query takes a lot of time to fetch the records when there are a number of people against a company. My question is, what would be a better reporting solution by design and technology to get results faster if I don't want to stick to oracle as in future data will grow. Logically, it would be to implement something that does work in parallel. Another option like Spark seems to be an overkill.

Comment: a possible solution is implementing a simple Warehouse model for your reportings, but it won't suffice your needs if I understood correctly "that does work in parallel", another solution came to my mind is using Materialized Views: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view]

Comment: The reports need to be near real time. Would that mean an operational data store? or would you advise something else? Materialized views are heavy and take up a lot of resources. Since this is a requirement for production and there are a number of reports, do you still see this as an option?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to use oracle as the existing solution for the parallel processing you can use spark as your data reconciliation framework. Though it needs some learning curve but by using spark sql you can use your own query to read data from oracle. You can read data in parallel though it depends on how many parallel sessions is been configured with your oracle profile. Please check with the DBA.

Another option is migrating to any nosql dB like Cassandra so you can horizontally scale your machines rather than vertically. But the migration won’t be an easy task and straight forward. As nosql database does not support joins by design so the data modelling should be changed accordingly. Once done you can use spark on top of it. You can also consider using Talend which has predefined spark component ready.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So Cassandra would be acting like an operational data store with near real time replication right? Also, parallel execution was meant to speed things up. If we keep parallel execution aside, what would be another solution we can use from simple reporting?

Comment: That’s correct Cassandra will contain your operational data. But I want to understand what is your data source. If it’s a transactional data then it should be a streaming data rather than batch. From the source you can design the architecture to use Kafka and top of it you can do all your transformation in near real time using spark and then load your resultant data to Cassandra for reporting where your BI tools will fetch data from

Comment: Source is Oracle, transactional database. Please excuse my ignorance, wouldn't using Spark for runtime transformation be better as that way Cassandara could act like a data lake and we could fetch whatever data we wanted in whatever way? Transforming and keeping the data would mean it cannot be used for any other thing other than the intended reports.

Comment: Even if you are using oracle we can also use spark as your data reconciliation framework. It will pull the data from oracle in parallel and transform the data for you. If you find the answer helpful please vote for it